# Graphics colour problem

Tags: graphics-card, far-cry-3

I am getting slightly peculiar graphics in Far Cry 3.  It looks rather like there is some colour quantisation going on - the shadows are pitch black, and change to lighter colours abruptly.  This is particularly noticeable is dark areas like caves, where it looks almost like an old 16bit colour game (although not that extreme).

I have also noticed it on faces, where there are quite clear contours between colour shades.  At the same time, some of the lighter areas are too light, e.g. the beach sand is amost completely white.  I have tried tweaking all the calibration settings, but nothing seems to get rid of it.  Has anyone else noticed this effect, or have any suggestions of what I can try to get rid of it?  I have a 24" Samsung HD LED monitor, and a radeon HD 7850 graphics card.  Other games look great, so I'm pretty sure its some setting in this game.

**Edit:**  Here's a screenshot showing what I mean:

<sup>(Click on image to view original, high resolution image.)</sup>
[image: screenshot]

I've tried updating the drivers, switching to DX9, but neither make any difference.

Comment: this may be baked-in lighting which would be untouched by settings (more or less). Additionally I know that Dead Island suffered from this to a certain extent when the gamma and or brightness was too high.

Comment: Try the newest Beta drivers from AMD, other than that, I think this question is too localized.

Comment: A screenshot would be helpful to illustrate the problem.

Comment: @Philipp Screenshot added.  Let me know if its not clear enough

Comment: Can you upload a higher resolution screenshot? (Current screenshot is 960 x 540 pixels only.) I think I experience a similar issue even with the [current v12.11 beta drivers](http://sites.amd.com/us/game/downloads/Pages/radeon_win7-64.aspx).

Comment: @galacticninja Full res screenshot added.

Comment: i got pretty much the same problem with GTX 680, tried changing all sttings on game and nothing, i bleieve it's probably some driver issues